# Laravel projects looking up localhost takes a long time to show the project page

Tags: laravel, localhost

My new laravel project takes 2 minutes to load a page.
When I start the program its

```
looking up localhost
```

Then

Looking up fonts.googlapis.com

After some time I see the loaded page then when I press a button to go to another page I get:

```
Read localhost


Looking up googleapis.com
```

Why is it taking so long and how can I stop it looking up googleapis?

Comment: remove all the references for googleapis.com from the view files and css/javascript

Comment: Is it a vanilla Laravel installation? What server are you using? What's the content of your site? Any heavy processing/fetching or just a simple plain page?

Comment: The setup is home network, server Leap15. plain simple page. I think it's composer2 there docs say this enviornment var COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 should allow  it to work. But it did not for me

Comment: Having done more research on this I don't think it's Composer. I now think it's Atom text editor, because my project works well until I edit/add code with Atom. Hence the problem arises.google no help

Comment: Well, I still working on this issue. Recently I found that localhost works well if I put this in the URL like so "localhost/projectname/". Once I add to the url thats when it slows. It takes 3 minutes to load. Hope this is helps.